# Must a module that is free of finite rank be finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Must a module that is free of finite rank be finitely generated? If so, what is an example of a free module that is not finitely generated? I think it should be. However, I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is finitely generated, after all it it isomorphic to a module $A^n$ for some $n$. (The finitely generated modules are exactly the quotients of the modules $A^n$.)